# How to retrieve a token from a request

Tags: java, spring, token

I understand that there is always a token that basically glued to the request, now i would like to get retrieve a token and stuck, would appreciate some thoughts. Thank you

```
  @GetMapping("/current")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getCurrent() {
 
    return ResponseEntity.ok(something);
}
```

in the method body i would probably implement another service where constructor is taking token as an argument for example then does some equality checks.

Comment: Which token are you mentioning? It would be appreciated if you can add extra details to your post along with samples of what your request / handler look like.

Comment: To answer your question we must know how you send token with your request. Do you send your token in `Authorization` header as  `bearer` token?

Comment: @mahfujasif   exactly , sorry guys  yes as exactly through Authorization Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller accept [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). then you can extract any header from it.

```
  @GetMapping("/current")
  public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getCurrent(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(something);
  }
```

If you don't want to take `HttpServletRequest` from controller you can `Autowire` it like this

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

or do the following

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Comment: do you know if there is a way to retrieve it without accepting HttpServlet as an argument?

Comment: Check the edited version and consider upvoting if it helped

Comment: Thanks yeh i know it can be part of a constructor but the reason why i have asked is because i have tests that using that method and i do not want to change anything there  however it looks like i would have to do that. I was hoping for some static method :D

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite hard to understand. Your "token" could be anything.

I'll try to answer your question in general:

For example, you have some option which is available only for registered users. If you are using jwt security, you generate tokens for users and "glue" them to request/response headers

For example (that's my current jUnit test):

```
protected MockHttpServletRequestBuilder getAuth(String url) {
    return MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url).header("Authorization", this.token);
}
```

And token is generated using jwt security, and after it's generated I can "glue" it to the headers. And I can just check what's in header and get token value.

So to check or get this token, you have to check what's in your header, just that simple :)

That's very general example. But the main idea is:
If you add something - you can get something. But if you haven't generated a token - you wouldn't get one "by default", because there is none, java do not generate tokens to any request. It's something you must first create first.

If you are uncommon with what I am talking about - please start from here:
https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: best wishes, tokens and their handling quite an interesting topic :) If my answer was useful - you can mark it, so others would know it was useful